# Help, IE7 mugged my divs and now they're running off the screen!

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

My site, http://hivechatter.com/, is super sexy for Firefox, Chrome, IE8, you name it:

[image]

But then along comes IE7, who mauls her divs so bad that they nearly run off the screen!  And for whatever reason the content within the divs is centered.  What the heck is going on here?  It seems to be something to do with the way IE7 interprets the left: percentage margins, but I can't figure it out.

[image]

For convenience and posterity's sake, below are the relevant portions of my css, with text formatting and other nonsense removed.  #container is the overall page container, #blue_box is the main content box, #left and #right are the columns in the blue box, #divider is the white line that separates them, #links is the light blue nav hovering below #blue_box.

```
#background {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -9999;
}

html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    background: no-repeat #222933;
    overflow: hidden;
}    

#container {
    position: relative;
    left: 34%;
    top: 10%;
    width: 50%;
    min-width: 450px;
    max-width: 700px;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 0;
}

#blue_box {
    position: relative; /* so that divider has appropriate height */
    width: 94%;
    padding: 3%;
    overflow: auto; /*needed so that div stretches with child divs*/
}

#left {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 44%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#right {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    width: 49%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}     

#divider{
    position:absolute;
    left:49%;
    top:6%;
    bottom:6%;
    border-left:1px solid white;
}

#links {
    float: right;
    width: 16em;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: I thought muggings didn't happen in NYC anymore.

Comment: Only code mugging...  :)

Comment: hmm, maybe I should revise to "IE7 scammed my divs" and go into an extended analogy involving mortgage-backed securities.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your position from relative to absolute for the container CSS.

Your problem is your image is just there with the container coming after it with a relative positioning.

Comment: That fixed the div issue, thanks much!  There's a time delay on accepting your answer, I'll come back.  In the meantime, I still need to figure out why IE7 centers the text in all the divs.  I haven't spent as much time trying to debug that, looking into it now.  If you see the problem would appreciate a tip.  Thanks again.

Comment: No problem. FWIW, Sam is right, it has to do with your text-align on body. You could do a conditional stylesheet or just nix the text-align:center altogether.

Comment: Sam, below, helped me fix the center alignment issue.

Answer (score 2):

IE7 is centering your container because you've set your body to `text-align:center`, then you're setting your container `left:34%`. IE is just adding those together for some reason. This is probably why your stuff is being centered in IE.  You could do a conditional stylesheet for IE7 and remove the text-align.

Comment: @Tim Koelkebeck this will solve you some potential issues in future. There is really problem with IE7, centered align and positioning.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize that rails was sneaking this into the default ie.css file that it automatically includes.  I added "text-align:center" to my container and that fixed it.  Apparently it's good to leave the center text-align in the body for an IE5 bug, though god help me if anyone using IE5 visits my site.

Comment: God help them if they're using IE5 period.

Comment: I'm curious if anyone is using IE5 at all. I don't see a trace of it here: http://marketshare.hitslink.com/browser-market-share.aspx?qprid=2

Answer (score 0):

Can't test at the moment if this will solve the issue but using margins on the blue box to position it instead of position: relative usually makes things a lot easier in the dark world of ancient Internet Explorers.

Comment: LookitsPuck has the solution i think